# CSS Button disabled state?

Tags: css, extjs

I am new on CSS,
How should I define my CSS class for catch button's disabled state?
There is my CSS class but it didn't work.

```
.mbutton:disabled{
background: transparent;
}
```

**EDIT**

There is JSfiddle example,
http://jsfiddle.net/sefiktemel/v7h9gczu/

Comment: share your html code or put this in fiddler...

Comment: Seems to be working as expected here: http://jsfiddle.net/wacuh2bd/

Comment: I added an answer for ExtJS buttons. You should specify on the title that you are working with ExtJS and what version of ExtJS you are using too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using ExtJS this will not work. You will have to add a custom class to to your button and then change your CSS to work with ExtJS.

Button Definition

```
Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
    text: 'Click me',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    handler: function() {
        alert('You clicked the button!');
    }
});

Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
    text: 'Click me',
    disabled: true,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    disabledCls :  'x-item-disabled mbutton', // this will add you mbutton class
    handler: function() {
        alert('You clicked the button!');
    }
});
```

Class Definition

```
.mbutton {
    background: transparent !important;
    cursor: not-allowed;
}

.mbutton .x-btn-inner {
    color: #666;
    cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/o93

Comment: Thank you Guilherme, it works but I also need to change backgroun-ımage  when disabled. The "background-image" properity of mbutton css class didn't work, do you have any idea?

Comment: What is your browser? i tested this with Chrome v43 only

Comment: I'm using same version Chrome, can you change background image in extJS with use mbutton class via setDisabled(true) method?

Comment: I thought you wanted a transparent background. If you want another image change the `background: transparent !important` to `background: transparent url("http://cdns2.freepik.com/free-photo/_17-312150302.jpg") no-repeat !important;`
I have updated the fiddle!

Answer (score 0):

```
Made even better.

.mbutton:disabled {
   cursor: not-allowed;
   background: transparent;

}
```

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/chtah59g/1/

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <style>
      button.mybutton:disabled { color: red;
        background: blue;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <button class="mybutton" disabled>Click me</button>
    <button class="mybutton"  >Click me</button>

  </body>

</html>
```

See http://plnkr.co/edit/3ZsqM8OHzcy7RogwBmwT?p=preview

Also, are you trying to add opacity?

```
    <style>
      button.mybutton:disabled { 
        color: red;
        background: blue;
        opacity: 0.4;
      }
    </style>
```

Comment: sorry man, I am using ExtJS 5, I don't define buttons like your answer. I set disabled the button with "button.setDisabled(true)" code. But it doesn't work.

Comment: When you inspect the element in your browser, is the button actually disabled?

Comment: It seems like that; class="x-btn x-unselectable x-box-item x-btn-default-small x-item-disabled x-btn-disabled everyone-button-disabled"

Comment: looks like Guilherme Lopes has a solution for ya.